# Replace Emoji with image while preserving it as an Emoji

Tags: javascript, php, emoji

I'd like to replace Emojis on my website with custom images. That itself would not be a problem in PHP:

```
$string = "This is a laughing emoji &#128514;";
echo str_replace($string, "&#128514;", ":'D"); //or replace with an image
```

However, how do I manage that if someone copies the text, they will be able to copy the text with the emoji and not the replaced image? Like keeping the char `&#128514;`  but only changing the outcome so they will look the same for every user. Is that even possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this would be to replace the emoji with an `<img>` image tag, but set the `alt` attribute of the image to the original emoji. Then, if the result is copied somewhere that only accepts text, the alt text will be used.

"Run" this snippet to see an example:

```html
Hello <img alt="&#128512;" src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDAAMAKIFAF5LAP/zxAAAANyuAP/gaP///wAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAUALAAAAAAMAAwAAAMlWLPcGjDKFYi9lxKBOaGcF35DhWHamZUW0K4mAbiwWtuf0uxFAgA7"> world!
<br/>
<textarea cols="25" rows="3">Paste here</textarea>
```

The emoji between the two words will look like a Gmail emoji, until you copy the entire line of text somewhere.

Of course, you can use a normal URL instead of a `data:` URL.

Comment: Thank you! I was just about to answer my one question because somehow writing it down untangled the knot in my brain. I should really get used to Rubber Ducking, how could I get stuck like this? :D

Answer (score 0):

No, each system has its own sets of fonts ( including emojis ) which is why they appear different on android vs iOS. The only way you would be able to add something would be outside of the system typeface, i.e. icon sets. You could either include images or links to images.

```
<img src="imageLocation" alt="altTextorImage">
```